# Angular Function Runs on Click but not when Initialized within Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Using angular, I have a function that when connected to a button (ng-click) in the view, runs as expected. For example, this runs and executes my function on click:

```
<button ng-click="foo()">add Foo!</button>
```

However, I would like to bypass having to click this button to run the function. So within my controller I have added:

```
foo();
```

This did not run my function, nor did using ng-init in the view, as such:

```
<div ng-init="foo()"></div>
```

I'm sure my code is not being executed, because it's designed to write to a database. On click, I see the expected results in my server's console log, and the data is written to the database. Using the above functions, the server's console log does not receive a response and no new data is written to the database.

Edit:
Here's my function, which sends a post to my server:

```
$scope.foo = function() {
    var SOName = $scope.bar.SO;
    var len = $scope.bar.FP.length;
    for(x=0;x<len;x++){
        $http.post('/track', {"track":$scope.bar.FP[x].name, "project":$scope.bar.SO}).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
};};
```

where

```
$scope.bar =
{"SO":"Do xx","QT":0,"RG":[{"name":"yy","LOE":0,"QT":0}],"FP":[{"name":"zz","LOE":3,"QT":0},{"name":"bb","LOE":1,"QT":0},{"name":"ff","LOE":1,"QT":0}],"VP":[],"QC":[{"name":"ww","LOE":15,"QT":0}],"ED":[{"name":"ee","LOE":0,"QT":0}]}
```

When trying to manually run the function, I changed `$scope.foo` to `var foo` and added `foo();` to try running the function.

Edit:
Tried simply calling `{{foo()}}` in the view - this was pretty finicky though. The page would either hang on load, or repeatedly send post after post of the same thing.

Comment: Lets see the function. Your justification of knowing its not running is not completely fool proof. If one of the variables in the function is not defined in the global scope etc it could run the function but never hit your server/database

Comment: In you controller you have a function ``foo`` on the ``$scope`` defined? then you need also call it like that ``$scope.foo()``

Comment: @BettySt good point. Forgot to mention that I DID change it to `var foo` when running that command from the controller. Will update my post when I'm at a computer.

Comment: @PatrickMurphy - just added the function to my original post.

Comment: Where is variable `x` in your function defined? Try  making the first line of foo() be a `console.log('entered foo function');` just to see if you can make sure the function is not running when you try and call it

Comment: @PatrickMurphy - I declare `x=0` in the `for` statement, is that what you mean? And the console.log message does appear, so the function is technically running, but the posts never happen.

Comment: there is no `var x;` or `var x = 0;`

Comment: Just changed it to `for(var x = 0 ; x < len ; x++ )` and does still not post. Shouldn't that not make a difference since the function executes on click?

Comment: Wasn't sure if it would change anything but it is syntactically correct. Try my answer I just added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Plunk on how to make function `foo()` be executed on page/controller load:

> http://plnkr.co/edit/acmJXYpzFZx39GYoOGIW?p=preview

On the plunk look into `IndexCtrl.js`, it contains examples on calling `foo()` as a part of `$scope`, as a controller local `function()`, and using `ng-init` inline tag as well.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that runs a function from within a controller

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.check = false;

    vm.f = function() {
      vm.check = true;
    }

    vm.f();
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl as c">
    {{c.check}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try re writing the `foo()` function to have the following http post in the for loop:

```
    var postdata = {"track":$scope.bar.FP[x].name, "project":$scope.bar.SO},
            req = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/track',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
                    },
                    data: $.param(postdata)
                };

    $http(req).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data); 
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            alert("error"+res);
    });
```

I just made sure that you had the right `Content-Type` header, and used the `$.param()` function to prepare the data. Also, I added a on error handler for the http request, that allows you to possibly see why the post is failing.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up. I wasn't able to do a straight copy and paste into the `for` loop, but that may be due to how my node.js server handles posts. It uses `requestify` to run posts. I could integrate the code, but it seems like what I'm trying to do should be possible fairly simply through angular.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this, I simply added a setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function() { $scope.foo() },4000);
```

Four seconds give the dependent function enough time to load.